# How do I display div depending on the link that's hovered?

Tags: html, jquery, css

How would display corresponding div based on the link a user hovers on?

I've managed to only get one div to work on hover the rest does not. I've tried multiple ways but looking for a pure css way to do this if it's possible.

```css
body {background: #000;}

.hide1 {
  display: none;
}
.hide2 {
  display: none;
}
.hide3 {
  display: none;
}

    
#myDIV:hover + .hide1 + .hide2 + .hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="myDIV" href="#">Test 1</a>

<a id="myDIV" href="#">Test 2</a>

<a id="myDIV" href="#">Test 3</a>


<div class="hide1">Test 11</div>

<div class="hide2">Test 22</div>

<div class="hide3">Test 33</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x9ksuwrm/2/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: The ID's are all the same now

Comment: I tried using unique ID's on this but nada

Comment: So use a class...

Comment: As @mplungjan said, if you have control over the html, using a `class` instead of `id` will simplify your css. If you describe better what the use-case is, you'll get a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a little javascript and add a class to those divs that are supposed to be hidden. Use javascript to remove the class during the hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDIV1, #myDIV2, #myDIV3").hover(function() {
    let index = $(this).data("index");
    $(`.hide${index}`).removeClass("hidden");
  }, function() {
    let index = $(this).data("index");
    $(`.hide${index}`).addClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
body {background: #000;}

.hide1, .hide2, .hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="myDIV1" data-index="1" href="#">Test 1</a>

<a id="myDIV2" data-index="2" href="#">Test 2</a>

<a id="myDIV3" data-index="3" href="#">Test 3</a>


<div class="hide1 hidden">Test 11</div>

<div class="hide2 hidden">Test 22</div>

<div class="hide3 hidden">Test 33</div>
```

Comment: This works, thansk. Tweaked it a bit

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selectors are incorrect. You are trying to interact on the hover with an element with the ID `myDIV` but such an element does not exist.

Moreover, the `+` selector selects the direct next element, you need to select an undirect sibling element. For this, you need to use the `~` selector.

Here is a working solution :

```css
body {background: #000;}

.hide1 {
  display: none;
}
.hide2 {
  display: none;
}
.hide3 {
  display: none;
}

    
#myDIV1:hover ~ .hide1,
#myDIV2:hover ~ .hide2,
#myDIV3:hover ~ .hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="myDIV1" href="#">Test 1</a>

<a id="myDIV2" href="#">Test 2</a>

<a id="myDIV3" href="#">Test 3</a>


<div class="hide1">Test 11</div>

<div class="hide2">Test 22</div>

<div class="hide3">Test 33</div>
```

Thomas.

Comment: This is not really nice to say that, ahah! I am not english and trying to write fast because I'm at work! :D

Comment: no worries, noticed your profile after I wrote it - was only a joke :)  I'll delete the pointless comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `~` selector for that work, rather than `+`.

Check the below code sample.

```css
.hide1,
.hide2,
.hide3 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV1:hover ~ .hide1 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
#myDIV1:hover ~ .hide2,
#myDIV1:hover ~ .hide3 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV2:hover ~ .hide2 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
#myDIV2:hover ~ .hide1,
#myDIV2:hover ~ .hide3 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV3:hover ~ .hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
#myDIV3:hover ~ .hide1,
#myDIV3:hover ~ .hide2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="myDIV1" href="#">Test 1</a>

<a id="myDIV2" href="#">Test 2</a>

<a id="myDIV3" href="#">Test 3</a>


<div class="hide1">Test 11</div>

<div class="hide2">Test 22</div>

<div class="hide3">Test 33</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are next to it works

```css
.hide1,
.hide2,
.hide3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

.myDIV:hover+.hide1 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.myDIV:hover+.hide2 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.myDIV:hover+.hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="myDIV" href="#">Test 1</a>
<div class="hide1">Test 11</div>
<a class="myDIV" href="#">Test 2</a>
<div class="hide2">Test 22</div>
<a class="myDIV" href="#">Test 3</a>
<div class="hide3">Test 33</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

However, don't do this. You are tied to where the elements are. They are required to be in proper order.

Don't go this pure CSS way. Use JS.

```css
body {background: #000;}

.hide1 {
  display: none;
}
.hide2 {
  display: none;
}
.hide3 {
  display: none;
}

    
#myDIV1:hover + #myDIV2 + #myDIV3 + .hide1,
#myDIV2:hover + #myDIV3 + .hide1 + .hide2,
#myDIV3:hover + .hide1 + .hide2 + .hide3 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="myDIV1" href="#">Test 1</a>

<a id="myDIV2" href="#">Test 2</a>

<a id="myDIV3" href="#">Test 3</a>


<div class="hide1">Test 11</div>

<div class="hide2">Test 22</div>

<div class="hide3">Test 33</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the code using `.hover()` and `.toggleClass()` from jQuery. Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[id^='div']").hover(function() {
    $($(this).data("rel")).toggleClass("hidden shown");
  }, function() {
    $($(this).data("rel")).toggleClass("hidden shown");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="div-1" data-rel="#hide-1" href="#">Test 1</a>
<a id="div-2" data-rel="#hide-2" href="#">Test 2</a>
<a id="div-3" data-rel="#hide-3" href="#">Test 3</a>
<div id="hide-1" class="hidden">Test 11</div>
<div id="hide-2" class="hidden">Test 22</div>
<div id="hide-3" class="hidden">Test 33</div>
```

I adjusted some of the attributed to be more specific. Hover has an In and Out function. Toggle Class will add/remove classes.